# Golang. Add a property to a struct at runtime

Tags: reflection, go

```
class type User {
    name string
}
```

Is it possible to add a field `age` at runtime?

Comment: Go is a compiled language. Meaning everything is done at that time.

Comment: It's a completely valid question to ask for someone who doesn't know. Why the -1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it is not possible.

Not even with Java or C++ syntax instead of valid Go.

Comment: In Java, you can certainly manipulate the byte code of the class at runtime. The [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework can manipulate existing classes or create new ones, add constructors, fields, etc.